# jobstart callback wont assign variable outside of function

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I have a job I want to run in the background of vim, and update my status line with the periodic results of that job.

I'm able to setup the timer, call the external job and get my response back. I'm able to `echom` the response and see it in `:messages`.

I am unable to get my global variable to take hold of the new value though.

Here is the vimscript:

```
let g:please_vim_why = 'an echo example'
let g:why_vim_why = -1
function! TimerRun(timer)
  call jobstart('date', {'on_stdout': 'TimerCallback'})
endfunction
function! TimerCallback(j, d, e)
  echom a:d[0]
  let g:why_vim_why = a:d[0]
endfunction
let timer = timer_start(2000, 'TimerRun', {'repeat': -1})
```

Run via `nvim -u godwhyvimwhydoyouhateme.vim` to load it as your vimrc.

Now if you go `:echo g:please_vim_why`, you'll see the response, 'an echo example'.

If you run `:messages`, you'll see a repeated output of the date.

**If you run `:echo g:why_vim_why` you will see no output.**

I thought maybe it might be `a:d` is scoped and gets garbage collected after the function, but `let g:why_vim_why = 'not a good joke' . a:d[0]`, sets the variable to 'not a good joke' but doesn't concatenate anything.

Why VIM? Why?

Comment: Nice detailed question with a minimum working example. +1  I observe the same behaviour in neovim 0.3.4 when I test your example, but don't know either why this is happening.

Comment: So you think it's not the code at fault? I can't figure *why* it wouldn't work, perhaps I should create an issue on GH? Vimscript is awkward to use though so I'm first leaning towards me not understanding it.

Comment: This seems to be neovim only. In Vim the example works as expected (slightly different syntax, like `job_start` instead of `jobstart`).

Comment: BTW: You should not [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606505/set-a-global-variable-from-a-function-argument-in-vimscript). See [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @purplelulu it would probably be worth it to raise an issue on the neovim github, seeing as it appears to be a neovim only issue as Ralf pointed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `on_stdout` callback will be called twice for each execution of `date` in this example.

First it will be called with the result from `date` as an array with two elements `['the-date', '']` where `''` is an artifact of the newline output by date. (If you run a job such as `echo -n "no new line"`, you'd only receive `['no new line']`.

Second it will be called with `['']` to signal `EOF` on `stdout`.

The second call is clobbering the first, which makes it appear as if the result is going missing somehow.

You can either check the length of the argument (i.e. `if len(a:d[0])...`) or pass the option `'stdout_buffered': 1` to `jobstart` to only receive output when all output from the command is collected.

All this is explained in `:h on_stdout`.

Comment: Glad to see you were able to fix your problem! I’ve edited the last sentence a bit to be less snarky for future readers, in the hope that it will make things feel more welcoming. Great answer!

Comment: Great job troubleshooting this one!